# Show that if $a_n > 0$ and $lim(na_n) = l$ with $l \not= 0$, then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> Show that if $a_n > 0$ and $lim(na_n) = l$ with $l \not= 0$, then
>   the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

$|na_n-l|< \epsilon$, $S_n=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$, suppose $\sum a_n$ converge then $S_n$ converge. So, $S_n$ is cauchy. $|S_n-S_{n-1}| < \epsilon $ => $|nS_n-nS_{n-1}| < \epsilon$, then $|na_n|<\epsilon$, but $l\not=0$, hence  contradiction

Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Explain this: $|S_n - S_{n-1}| < \varepsilon \implies |nS_n - nS_{n-1}| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: The quick way: $0 < a_n \sim \ell/n$, hence diverges by comparison theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W.L.G,we suppose $l>0$.
From $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=l>l/2>0$, we know there exists $N$ such that when  $n\geq N$
$$na_n>l/2,$$ that is to say when  $n\geq N$
$$a_n>\frac{l}{2n},$$
by the comparative method of positive series,
the series $\sum a_n$ diverges!

Answer (score 2):

In your proposed solution, when you multiply $\vert S_n - S_{n-1} \vert$ by $n$, $\epsilon$ should also be multiplied by $n$. Hence it doesn't work.

**Hint**

You have $a_n \ge \frac{l}{2n}$ for $n$ large enough. As the harmonic series diverges, $\sum a_n$ also diverges.

Comment: Yeah, but we can take as $ϵ$ any positive number so take it as $ϵ/n$. Will it work? I saw a similar trick several times.

Comment: No. And it is critical that you understand why! You have to fix $\epsilon$ at the start of your proof in order to select the right $n$. If you divide $\epsilon$ by $n$, then your $n$ depends$ on itself and it is not possible to find it in order to verify Cauchy criteria.

Comment: In fact i was using the idea that $\lim{ca_n} = ca $, where $ |ca_n-ca| < ϵ$ then $|c||a_n-a|<ϵ$ and we can choose $N$ such that  $|a_n-a|<ϵ/|c|$, then $|c||a_n-a|<ϵ$. What is the difference between these two cases? Why can't I take $N$ sufficiently big here?

Comment: You can do that for a **fixed** $c$. In what you did, $c$ is not fixed but equal to $n$. And it is $n$ that you're trying to find!

Comment: Oh... Thank you. Now I understand.